# difference between donna and supercop implementations for ed25519 signature scheme

Tags: cryptography, ed25519, ed25519-donna

While looking up the existing implementations of the ed25519 signature scheme I found out that the donna implementation (found [here](https://github.com/floodyberry/ed25519-donna)) produces signatures that are not verifiable by supercop implementation (found [here](https://github.com/orlp/ed25519)), but supercop signatures are verifiable by donna implementation. Can somebody explain why two implementations of supposedly the same signature scheme produce only partially compatible signatures? What am I missing? Here is an example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
secret key = 50f26a6d0e454337554274d703033c21a06fecfcb0457b15214e41ea3228ac51e2b9f0ca0f6510cfdd24325ac6676cdd98a9484336ba36c876fd93aa439d8b72
public key = eddaef2fab3d1412ea1f2517b5a50439c28c27d6aefafce38f9290c17e1e7d56

donna signature = f4b79662b1973be8774c5d23044fe4b25858e7c362923e1fc99cc98e89e099c3f574dca3e47d7a131b43860fabc34b6764ccabb4f9f21b6cae54be5fc8193103
//not verifiable by supercop

supercop signature = 2f0ae6396d4d72fb47c12df6560747f20dc675e0b2d7e711caf68a03ced9309b9abd736cb204e789b95c2f08e0be4254ce69974a4064e40ce7094e288b7cbf03
//verifiable by donna
```

To obtain the results above, I used **ed25519_sign()** from **ed25119-donna** and **supercop** library  (they are called the same in both libraries).

To verify the signatures i used **ed25519_sign_open()** from **ed25519-donna** and **ed25519_verify()** from **supercop**.